# Python xlsxwriter row-column notation for range dictionary of sparkline

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

The row-column notation of xlsxwriter works very well for me on everything so far, e.g. adding a chartseries. Also, the add_sparkline works as expected.

However, I can't get the 2 to work together... what am I doing wrong?

These 2 work perfect:

```
worksheet.add_sparkline(2, 2, {'range': 'D2:I2' }) # add sparkline to row 2
chart.add_series({'values': ['Recent', row,colstart,row,colend]})
```

This does not work:

```
worksheet.add_sparkline(2, 2, {'range': [row,colstart,row,colend] })
```

Many thanks in advance! Wouter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list syntax in XlsxWriter sparklines for `range` (and `location`) doesen't support row-column syntax. Instead it is used for a feature of sparklines called [grouped-sparklines](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_sparklines.html#grouped-sparklines).

To use row-column syntax in your case you can use one of the [cell utility functions](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html#cell-utility-functions) such as `xl_range`:

```
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_range

# ...
worksheet.add_sparkline(2, 2, {'range': xl_range(row,colstart,row,colend)})
```